# index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, indexoutofboundsexception

I am very new to xcode please guide me to correct the error, My code is,

```
//Set our mapView
[MapViewC setRegion:myRegion animated:NO];
CLLocation *someLocation=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:someLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] addressDictionary];
    addressOutlet=[dictionary valueForKey:@"Street"];
    City=[dictionary valueForKey:@"City"];
    State=[dictionary valueForKey:@"State"];

    if (addressOutlet!=NULL&&City!=NULL)
    {
        NSString *SubTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",addressOutlet,City,State];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=SubTitle;


    }
    else if (addressOutlet==NULL&&City!=NULL)
    {
        NSString *SubTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,",City,State];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=SubTitle;

    }
    else if (addressOutlet!=NULL&&City==NULL)
    {
        NSString *SubTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,",addressOutlet,State];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=SubTitle;
    }
    else if(addressOutlet==NULL&&City==NULL)
    {
        NSString *SubTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",State];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=SubTitle;

    }




}];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK an array can be empty, in which case the following statement will cause an exception:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] addressDictionary];
//                                                    ^
```

So guard against it, with something like:

```
if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] addressDictionary];
    ....
}
```

I haven't read the API docs for that completion handler, but you can *probably* test if `error` is non-`nil` and act accordingly (i.e. if `error != nil` respond to error, else process the `placemarks` array).

Comment: @user3747282 I've no idea what you mean.

Comment: it terminates in this below line of code, NSString *latOrgstring = [latitudeString objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: @Ragul I detect a help vampire.  I believe I have answered your question and I will not answer questions about other issues you are having.  Start a new question with some actual details for your next problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot i got answer